# Calling delete on a pointer to a non-heap object

Tags: c++, memory

Confusing question for me:

```
C c1;
C *p = &c1;
delete p;
```

what could possibly be the output?

Comment: What output? The one you might get from the undefined behaviour?

Comment: I took the liberty to make the question's title more specific to the question itself.

Comment: Chris, like, would would happen. Compliation error? Runtime error? Undefined behaviour?
juan, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything really. It's undefined behavior `delete`ing what wasn't allocated with `new`.

Comment: Note  the program is allowed to output even though there is no output instruction

Comment: @JanDvorak that's what I said - "Anything really"

Comment: I would expect the program to complain on the _first_ deletion.

Comment: I would like to test but I'm afraid several copies of "nasal.exe" might be launched in the background.

Comment: Cant it be that C is a class or struct that has a constructor in which there is an allocation. So `C c1;` actually is equal to `C c1();` `delete`ing would not be a problem? (I am just asking.)

Comment: @FredrickGauss no. Also, `C c1();` is a function declaration (check out *most vexing parse*.

Comment: Most systems will complain?  I doubt it.  On most systems I've seen, the `delete` will corrupt memory somewhere, either crashing immediately, or causing a crash much later in the code.  But I doubt any will complain about the double delete.  Especially if C is a POD, for example.

Comment: @JamesKanze When I said complain, I meant a runtime exception. That's why I said system, not compiler.

Comment: Even then, the wording is poor.  There _is_ no double delete here, and what will cause the system to complain (although I've seen more than one in which it would be a no-op, at least some of the time) is the `delete` of something not allocated by `new`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I just removed that completely, wasn't really useful anyway.